# What does "I'm in for a million" mean in this context?

Tags: phrases

In The Late Late Show, James Corden and Katy Perry talk about starting a business and Katy Perry says "I'm in for a million". What does that mean?

Comment: That she wants to invest one **MILLION** dollars.

Comment: It's a betting idiom: to be in [the game] for some amount.

Comment: There is also a related idiom in English: "[in for a penny, in for a pound](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_for_a_penny,_in_for_a_pound)," meaning that a small debt may carry the same consequences as a larger one.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, it means she's *interested in investing 1 million dollars* in whatever idea they were just discussing.

I'd have to see the clip to give an opinion on whether that's a sincere investment promise or (more likely) a joke as part of a bit.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://www.cbs.com/shows/late-late-show/photos/1007551/best-moments-in-carpool-karaoke-with-katy-perry/)

Comment: Also, the phrase was actually used [here](http://investorshub.advfn.com/boards/read_msg.aspx?message_id=128697147).